# Set up email notification in Teamcity

Tags: email, teamcity

I would like to set up email notification for every "build failure" in Teamcity. However, I would like to send the notifications to only one email address, but not to the group. How can I achieve this. Please help. I am using Teamcity Professional 8.1.4 (build 30168)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to send the mail to yourself, You need to setup "Notifications".You can basically setup the exact scenario you described which is send email whenever build fails. You can do this for yourself or any other user id, or a group of users.

If you want to setup a notification for someone else, they can set it up in their "Notifications " section or you can set it up for them if you are an admin

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you provide me the steps to set up for a single email address. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this earlier by making  a new group, Admins, including only me. Then I sent mail to that group. It sounds like your group email is working , right?

Comment: Yes, I created a group but with only one member in it. Now, Teamcity is sending email notifications to this group (actually to only one email address). Thanks Biswajit_86 and Thanks AnneTheAgile

Comment: Hmm, I got -15points for my reply, which seems odd given you thought it was helpful @Bhaskar :). Usually if the admins vote me down I just go with the flow and delete my item, but here I think I actually added value. In fact, you followed my suggestion to solve the issue. I'll wait and see  about this post :)